# C++ multiple lines input

Tags: c++, boost, input, char

So I need to create a char buffer containing 4 lines of text (EN_us) like

```
first line
line with some number like 5
line 3
empty line
```

What is correct way of getting such char buffer from user and how to get its length?

Comment: Is this homework?  Its cool if it is, but we like to know.

Comment: @John, I don't think so, a lot of qs recently from @Kabumbus.

Comment: do you generaly want to read until some kind of input termination or is it just these four fixed lines?

Comment: Its more friends and I studding C++... On some school level project... some simle video streaming client+server type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting a buffer like that, it might be easier to read four lines into separate `string`s from the standard input using `getline` (use a loop if you prefer):

Then the total data length is the sum of the individual `string` lengths.  Alternatively use this method to retrieve the data from the user and then concatenate them into a four-line `stringstream`.

Combined code example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string s[4];
size_t length(0);

std::ostringstream output;

for (size_t index = 0; index < 4; ++index)
{
    getline(std::cin, s[index]);
    length += s[index].length();

    output << s[index] << std::endl;
}

output.flush();
streamoff streamLength = output.tellp();
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd go for a `std::string lines[4]; for(...) std::getline(std::cin, lines[i]);` Makes it easier to change and less of a pain to write!

Comment: @André, agreed, I'll change this.